# Order column sums excluding factor columns

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 19 obs of 33 variables. The first two columns contain factors and the rest are numerical.
Eg.

```
ID  Status  Bacteria1  Bacteria2
P1  Patient 2.86       7.93
C1  Control 83.93      8.23
```

I'd like to find the column sums of the numerical columns and order them decreasing, with the two factor columns remaining in that position.

I have tried this:

```
test[,order(colSums(test[,3:33]), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

The two factor columns are moved and the columns don't really seem to be ordered by column sums.

I know I could do it by making a new dataframe with just `[,3:33]` and then `cbind` the factor columns back to the new dataframe. But I am trying to become more streamlined with R

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order` to get the order in which columns should be arranged. Try -

```
df[c(1:2, order(colSums(df[,3:ncol(df)], na.rm = TRUE), decreasing = TRUE) + 2)]
```

`1:2` keeps the first 2 columns constant. `order` would return the correct order for dataframe with `3:ncol(df)` columns, `+2` is needed to offset the first 2 columns.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. I'll remember the trick about keeping  columns constant

Answer (score 0):

One option could be:

```
ind <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
data.frame(df[!ind], df[ind][order(colSums(df[ind]))])

  ID  Status Bacteria2 Bacteria1
1 P1 Patient      7.93      2.86
2 C1 Control      8.23     83.93
```